# Reads Path>File as String - "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'open'" Why?

Tags: python, python-2.7

In the code below it reads the out_file as a string and I can't seem to figure out why. If I do not treat it as a string then it says the file location is incorrect. It reads the src_dir fine apparently. Thanks in advance for any help. I'm very new to python and teaching myself.

```
import os
import os.path
import shutil

'''This is supposed to read through all the text files in a folder and
copy the text inside to a master file.'''

#   This gets the source and target directories for reading writing the
#   files respectively

src_dir = r'E:\filepath\text_files'
out_file = r'E:\filepath\master.txt'
files = (os.listdir(src_dir))
def valid_path(dir_path, filename):
    full_path = os.path.join(dir_path, filename)
    return os.path.isfile(full_path)
file_list = [os.path.join(src_dir, f) for f in files if valid_path(src_dir, f)]    


#   This should open the directory and make a string of all the files
#   listed in the directory. I need it to open them one by one, write to the
#   master file and close it when completely finished.


open(out_file, 'a+')
with out_file.open() as outfile:
    for element in file_list:
        open(element)
        outfile.append(element.readlines())

out_file.close()

print 'Finished'
```

Comment: The python site has some good reference material for all things python... Including how to open files...http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all wrong:

```
open(out_file, 'a+')
with out_file.open() as outfile:
    for element in file_list:
        open(element)
        outfile.append(element.readlines())

out_file.close()
```

The correct **usage** of `open`, `read`, `write`, `readlines` is:

```
f = open(path_to_file, ...)
f.write(data)
data = f.read()
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()
```

[*the above is not a valid or working script, just an example of how to invoke each method*]

So to help you in your specific use case:

```
with open(out_file, 'a+') as outfile:
    for element in file_list:
        with open(element) as infile:
            outfile.write(infile.read())
```

1. You don't need to `close()` if you use a `with` close (that the whole point of `with`: it closes for you).
2. Since you want to read everything from one file and write to another, use `read()` rather than `readlines()`: i.e. get the whole lot, write the whole lot.

If you really want to use `readlines()`, then something like this would be better:

```
outfile.write(''.join(infile.readlines())
```

Comment: It's worth noting that the examples of using `open`, `read`, etc. do not form a useful or meaningful program taken together. Their purpose is to demonstrate which ones are functions, which ones are methods, and what object the methods are supposed to be called on.

Comment: Thanks! That would probably address the error message I'm receiving.

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks again for answering my question.